# "CancellationTokenSource" GetHashCode

Tags: c#

Is the hadhcode returned by `CancellationTokenSource.GetHashCode()` constant for the duration of the token instance ?

That is is it safe to hold cancellation tokens in ie a HashSet ?

```
ImmutableHashSet<CancellationTokenSource> TokensSet = new();
TokensSet = TokensSet.Add(myToken);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `CancellationTokenSource` does not override the `GetHashCode()` method, so that the implementation of `Object.GetHashCode()` is used. This means that the hash code remains the same over the whole lifetime of the instance.